# Prepare data at ID,Month level in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that is something like this:

```
ID  Date
1   10/04/2015
1   28/04/2015
1   14/07/2015
1   30/07/2015
1   30/08/2015
2   10/04/2016
2   28/04/2016
2   14/05/2016
2   30/05/2016
```

but i am trying to achieve like:

```
ID  Date
1   28/04/2015
1   30/07/2015
1   30/08/2015
2   28/04/2016
2   30/05/2016
```

Could you please help me .

Comment: Can you add some more detail? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select id,
           [Date],
           row_number() over (partition by id, datepart(month, [date]) order by [Date] desc) [rn]
    from (
    select id, 
           --date convrsion, 103 - British/French - your style
           convert(date, [date], 103) [Date]
    from @MyTable
    ) a
) b where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, it's better to add datepart(year, [date])

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the logic of expected result but the query below would work.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable 
WHERE DAY([Date])>=28;
```

See [How to get Day, Month and Year Part from DateTime in Sql Server](http://sqlhints.com/2014/02/03/how-to-get-day-month-year-and-time-part-from-datetime-in-sql-server/)